# Why do some of the item costs on the wiki show two numbers?

Tags: dota-2

For example, [the Shadow Blade](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Shadow_Blade) shows `3000 (1000)`

What is the (1000) supposed to represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number in rounded brackets is the cost of recipe that is needed to craft the item.

For example, the total cost of Shadow Blade is 3300 (not 3000), split in:

- Claymore: 1400
- Quarterstaff: 900
- Shadow Blade recipe: **1000**

If an item does not need a recipe to be crafted the Wiki shows only a number.

Comment: so basically you don't save any money by crafting it yourself vs buying the item directly

Comment: Yep, correct...

Comment: Yeah there's no real crafting in Dota2. You either have all of the pieces of the "recipe"/upgraded item, which makes it, or you don't. The cost of recipes is something a lot of LoL players have trouble understanding, I don't really get why.

Comment: @Decency Most likely because in LoL the recipe cost is hidden and rolled into the combined item. e.g. Buying a 2 component item in DotA is X + Y + Recipe = Z. Buying a 2 component item in LoL is X + Y <= Z, where Z has the hidden recipe cost built in. LoL has chosen to display it one way, and unfortunately the transition from LoL -> DotA in that regard is less obvious because of the missing information, as opposed to vice versa of DotA -> LoL where you have pre-existing information.